# Infinite sum of transmitted parallel light fields

Tags: optics, electric-fields, geometric-optics, interference, interferometry

I'm currently studying
optics and came across the possibility of retrieving the original electric (light field) from a pair of partially reflecting mirrors, but  I am confused by several inconsistencies found on the lecture note:

---

For the Nth electric field, I got
$$E_N=t^2r^{2(n-1)}E_0e^{ik(2n-1)d/cos(\theta)}=E_1(r^2e^{i \phi})^{N-1} \tag{1}$$ (this is different to the one found on the note but with $r+t=1$ I'm fairly confident that (1) is correct).

So the infinite sum should be
$$E_t=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}E_n=\frac{E_0t^2e^{ikd/cos(\theta)}}{1-r^2e^{i(2kd/cos(\theta))}}=\frac{E_0t^2}{1-r^2}$$
(again, different right until the last line...)
for $\frac{\phi}{2}=2m\pi$ (as opposed to $\phi=m2\pi$ stated in my lecture note).
The lecturer also claims that $1-r^2=t^2$ (this is also used in the intensity part so was unlikely to be a typo) but the entire derivation seems to follow from the fact that $r+t=1$ (so it seems impossible that $E_t=E_0$)?

To conclude my questions:

1. Why is it that $r^2+t^2=1$ when clearly $r+t=1$?

---

[image]

Comment: dang, I just leaned about Fabry Perot interferometers so if I have time I'll come back later and see if I can help you out if this still isn't answered

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the question is here. Are you asking if $r+t=1$? Or if $r^2+t^2=1$? Or how to do the interference sum? Or all three of those?

Comment: Both the sum and $r+t=1$, I'll make it clearer in the edit, apologies.

Comment: How are $t$ and $r$ defined? Just as fractions? If so, then their sum must be one, as you say.

Comment: Look here: https://ccahilla.github.io/fabryperot.html It says there that "when the phase is mod$2\pi$". Or doesn't it?

Comment: In the link, you can adjust the reflectivities of both mirrors, on top.

Comment: @Deschele Schilder Yes I think they're are fractions but the author has repeatedly used $t^2+r^2=1$ (please see lecture note) and I'm very confused by this.

Comment: Look at the second page here:https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/EAA68B97-DD0B-6598-2574A179644FFB69_277869/josaa-31-2-411.pdf?da=1&id=277869&seq=0&mobile=no  On the upper part of the page (left and right) $h_b$ (said to be equal to $\sqrt{r^2+t^2}$) is assumed to be 1. So $r^2+t^2=1$. Reference to a hypotenuse is made. Is this of any use?

Comment: @Deschele Schilder  Could you post the link again please? It doesn't seem to work for some reason. Thanks

Comment: Here it is:  https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/EAA68B97-DD0B-6598-2574A179644FFB69_277869/josaa-31-2-411.pdf?da=1&id=277869&seq=0&mobile=no